# What are the main clause and subordinate clauses in this sentence as spoken by a four-year-old child with DLD

Tags: grammar, psychology

> **And they be happy they got the airplane.**

I have said one main clause is ‘they be happy’. The second main clause is ‘they got the airplane’.

Is this correct? Are there any subordinating clauses in this sentence?

> they be happy:

They - **subject**
be - **verb**
happy - **predicative complement**

> they got the airplane.

they - **subject**
got - **verb**
the airplane - **direct object**

Does all this seem correct?

The child is a 4-year-old client. I am a speech therapy student.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126055/discussion-on-question-by-user424984-can-someone-help-me-identify-the-main-claus).